# How to force unwrap Optional String stored as Any

Tags: reflection, swift

How do i force unwrap an optional value thats "stored" as `Any`?

```
let optionalString: String? = "optional string"
let anyString: Any = optionalString

if let unwrappedString = anyString as? String {
     println(unwrappedString)
    // does not recognize the anyString as an optinal String
}
```

How do i write an if statement that force unwraps the value stored in `anyString` and prints the `optionalString` value? I have to do it only accessing the `anyString` attribute.

The use case for this is to get values out of `MirrorType`, which stores the attribute values as `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

**Ignore answer as not really providing a solution - the problem looks like a compiler bug**

I'm not deleting it by now so readers know what I tried, and how I misunderstood the real question:

> How to unwrap an optional value stored in a variable of `Any` type

Also be sure to read comments.

---

In your code you are using optional binding. Forced unwrapping instead uses the postfix `!` operator:

```
println(optionalString!)
```

but if the optional string contains a nil value, that throws a runtime exception. So unless you are 100% sure it's not nil, I recommend using optional binding:

```
if let unwrappedString = optionalString {
    println(unwrappedString)
}
```

---

That said, if you have an optional string stored in an `Any` variable, using optional downcasting and optional binding  you can extract as follows:

```
var anyString: Any? = "optional string" as String?

if let unwrappedString = anyString as? String {
    println(unwrappedString)
}
```

If you want to use a forced downcast, that's simply:

```
println(anyString as String)
```

but as in forced unwrapping, this causes a runtime exception if `anyString` is nil.

---

If the `anyString` variable is not optional, things are even simpler, because there's no optional binding, just optional downcasting, although the related code looks exactly the same:

```
var anyString: Any = "optional string"

if let downcastedString = anyString as? String {
    println(downcastedString)
}
```

Comment: So it's not possible to check Any for its content? I'm not allowed to change it to Any?, since its the reflection API that i'm actually using

Comment: you aren't creating an Optional string with the last edit, try declaring the Any the way i do in the code example, and you will see that the if let check won't recognize it.

Comment: I can't find a solution - it's easy to label malfunctions as bugs... but this really sounds like that. `anyString` cannot be unwrapped because it's not an optional, and downcasting to an optional doesn't work because it says it's a more optional type.

Comment: Damn. Submitted a support request to Apple to get them to clearify what Any can do now. Thanks for the help along the way.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for missing the real question... I'm interested in knowing the solution, so if you have any news please report it here

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Any then you can test if it's optional and it it's nil by using something as:

```
    var anyValue: String? = "The string"
    var theValue: Any = anyValue
    let mi:MirrorType = reflect(theValue)
    if mi.disposition == .Optional {
      if mi.count == 0 { return NSNull() } // Optional.None
      let (name,some) = mi[0]
      theValue = some.value
    }
```

Now theValue will just be a String and not an Optional String. So you can cast it and use it as a String.